# MySQL - Show CREATE TABLE result by giving Table name

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the query that will take a table that is already created and populated with data, and show how it would have been created? The result of this query looks just like what the original CREATE TABLE query would have looked like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is it:

```
show create table TABLENAME;
```

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-create-table.html)

Why does your title say `INSERT TABLE` when your question is about `CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: Isn't it interesting that the the correct title now actually contains the answer?